# Fatal error in wordpress htdocs

Tags: fatal-error, wp-error

I need help with this

> Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /homepages/25/d502821911/htdocs/...../wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 757

Comment: I'd guess you're trying to use a really old WordPress version with a modern (>7.4) PHP. However I can't find that syntax in script-loader in a few old versions. Can you tell us which WordPress version you're using? Can you show us line 757 and a few either side please?

Comment: Hola @Rup esta es la línea de código:  $init_obj = '';
 foreach ( $tinymce_settings as $key => $value ) {
  if ( is_bool( $value ) ) {
   $val       = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
   $init_obj .= $key . ':' . $val . ',';
   continue;
  } elseif ( ! empty( $value ) && is_string( $value ) && (
   ( '{' == $value{0} && '}' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
   ( '[' == $value{0} && ']' == $value{strlen( $value ) - 1} ) ||
   preg_match( '/^\(?function ?\(/', $value ) ) ) {
   $init_obj .= $key . ':' . $value . ',';
   continue;
  }

Comment: esa es la linea 757 y 758